# If I was developing a Bitcoin wallet, should I support both legacy and compatibility addresses?

Tags: address, segregated-witness, utxo, p2sh, p2pkh

To receive funds, I was thinking of giving a user the option of displaying two QR codes:

1. Legacy - `p2phk` e.g. `1AKDDsfTh8uY4X3ppy1m7jw1fVMBSMkzjP`
2. Compatibility - `p2sh(p2wpkh)` e.g. `34nSkinWC9rDDJiUY438qQN1JHmGqBHGW7`

Is it safe to only give them the option of receiving to a "compatibility" address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Displaying two would be justified if you were asking about a BC1 p2wpkh vs a 3xxx p2sh(p2wpkh) because not everything supports BC1 but its pretty good to use when supported.

Displaying two isn't useful between p2pkh/p2sh as you've asked about because p2sh is supported everywhere and many wallets and services have used p2sh exclusively for a long time.

Supporting plain p2pkh is not something I'd recommend a new wallet bother doing. That development and testing effort would better be spent on newer functionality.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to only give them the option of receiving to a "compatibility" address?

Yes. All modern wallet software understand P2SH and can create transactions that send to such addresses.

Comment: What's the implication of displaying both? i.e. for a single compressed public key, you'll have utxo associated with multiple addresses (if people send to both.)

Comment: A UTXO is only associated with a single encumberment (script) - The fact that one private key controls multiple outputs is irrelevant. However, you should be using HD wallets to derive keys for BIP44/49/84 following standard paths, in which case they private key will not be common.

Comment: @RaghavSood So even if the address to be generated is p2sh(p2wpkh), I should derive from the HD wallet at say, m / 84' / 0' / 0' / 0 / 0?

Comment: Actually I just noticed bip49 refers to this particular example.